# Samba File Server not Working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, samba, services

since yesterday my Filesharing on Windows doesn't work. And the problem might that the SmbServer is not running at all. If I check netstat there is no process running on Port 445. Do you have an idea how to solve this.

It isnt even possible to access the files on the same pc. With "\\192.168.1.103" where 192.168.1.103 is the IP address

Answer (score 0):

Which network profile are you using in Windows 10?   I would try the following

1. Open Settings.
2. List item
3. Click Network & Internet.
4. The list of network and Internet related settings appears.
5. Click Ethernet or Wi-Fi, depending on the type of network you’re
   connected to.
6. Information about the network you’re connected to appears.
7. If you’re connected to a wired network, click the name of the
       network you’re connected to. If you’re connected to a wireless
       network, click Advanced Options under the list of available wireless
       networks.
8. The list of settings available for your network connection is shown.
       Set the Find Devices and Content switch to Off or On, depending on
       whether or not you want to turn on sharing.

Another option would be to check your windows firewall settings to make sure that you are allowing incoming traffic over SMB.  I believe the built in firewall rule you want to enable is called **File and Printer Sharing (SMB In).**

[image]

Comment: Firewall seems to be okay, even if the firewall is disabled it wont work. And File Sharing is enabled

Comment: What happens if you right click on a file or folder, go to properties, manually share the folder then attempt to access it via \\ipaddress\sharedfolder\. I would expect to get some sort of an error when trying to add a shared folder if SMB was somehow disabled?  Is the machine on a domain by any chance?

Comment: Could you post the output of netstat -an in your original post?